# Visual Studio 2008 TFS to connect to a TFS 2010 Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

What do I need to install to connect my Visual Studio 2008 to TFS 2010 Server?

This blog

http://technical.blog.thomashundley.com/post/2011/07/21/Team-Explorer-2008-and-TFS-2010.aspx

suggests installing SP1 and then installing ....

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10834

Is that correct?

Comment: You basically answered it yourself :-)

Comment: I don't see why this has been down voted, I was missing the crucial step of installing VS 2008 Team Explorer which was missing from the blog post I quoted. Dylan Smith gave me the correct installation steps and a much better blog post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install VS 2008 Team Explorer, then VS 2008 SP1, then the Forward Compatibility Update in that order.

See this link for details and links to the installers:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2012/01/03/tfs-2010-what-service-packs-and-hotfixes-should-i-install.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hm... yes. The overview of the KB article said it pretty clear. What makes you worry?

> This is an update for the 2008 SP1 version of Visual Studio Team
>   System Team Explorer and allows the 2008 SP1 version to work with the
>   Team Foundation Server 2010. The update will allow teams to move
>   forward and use the Team Foundation Server 2010 server even if part of
>   the team continues to use the Team Explorer 2008 SP1 client.

Comment: The "Forward Compatibility Update" bit. I don't have a TFS Explorer installed so its not an update its a fresh install